# Matrix sign function?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to use the matrix sign function, implemented as [signm](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/2360/versions/1/previews/matrixcomp/signm.m/index.html) in Matlab. Is there a Mathematica version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be very efficient, but I think you can use the following:

```
MatrixSignDecomposition[m_] := With[{s = m . MatrixPower[m . m, -1/2]},
    {s, Inverse[s] . m}
]
```

For example:

```
SeedRandom[1];
A = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}]

{s, n} = MatrixSignDecomposition[A]
```

> {{0.817389, 0.11142, 0.789526}, {0.187803, 0.241361, 0.0657388}, {0.542247,
> 0.231155, 0.396006}}

> {{{0.202042, -1.01741, 1.6096}, {0.346034, 1.4412, -0.698004}, {0.814634,
> 1.03867, -0.643241}}, {{0.846876, 0.149016, 0.730047}, {0.175016, 0.225057,
> 0.0915319}, {0.512144, 0.192773, 0.456728}}}

Check:

```
Eigenvalues[s]
A == s . n
```

> {1., 1., -1.}

> True